# easySilder 1.7 jquery - moce to latest selected slide after page reloads

Tags: jquery, slider, easyslider

I have a menu implemented with easySlider 1.7.

Code is like this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <?
            $rezultat = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT catid,name FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC");
            $count = 1;
            echo "<li>";
            while($camp = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat))
            {
                if ($count <= 7)
                {
                    $count++;
                    if ($pagina == $camp['catid'])
                    {
                        echo "<a href='index.php?catid=";
                        echo $camp['catid'];
                        echo "' style='color: #F00;'>".$camp['name']."</a><br />";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<a href='index.php?catid=";
                        echo $camp['catid'];
                        echo "'>".$camp['name']."</a><br />";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $count = 1;
                    echo "</li><li>";   
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, after I click a link on the menu, the page reloads and i loose track of "previous current slide" where I have the selected link.

How can i go to that slide after reload or make it default slide ?

PS: Works with ajax but if i use ajax i have problem with some other php generated javascript variables that depends of each link. You can see a preview at: http://5election.com. Notice the scrolling menu on the bottom left side that's I'm having problems with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the hyperlink the current slide.

In this way, when the page loads, you will know from where it came.

Comment: not really working. added: <li name='$count'> and on links i now have: http://localhost/5p/index.php?catid=17#count, but after i click the link and page reloads i still have first slide.